# What's the best way to search properties of a class in wpf?

Tags: properties

I'm still new to WPF. Is there a website or document for property of certain class?

For example, I want to find a properties of trigger. When I search for "wpf trigger property" on google, I see few msdn sites like [Trigger.Property Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.property(v=vs.110).aspx). However, it does not tell me much, other than there are IsMouseOver, and IsPressed. Which is really annoying and not helpful. There are few classes that has list of their available properties like [ButtonBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase(v=vs.110).aspx), but others do not.

Could anyone recommend me a better way to search?

Comment: `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` are not properties of `Trigger` class. These are properties of another classes that can be used as values for `Trigger.Property`. If you want to know what values can be passed to this property - **any** `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: What do you really want to do? This seems like an xy problem. Do you want to use reflection or do you just need some documentation?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I was hoping to see a documentation that will help me figure out what properties that I can use for certain class. For example, I want to create a right click trigger. My ideal approach will be search if there is something like OnRightClick or RightButtonDown property in the Trigger class. But apparently I can't find it such way. So I was asking which will be the better way to search such property.

Comment: @tk.hfes In that case you will find all the information you need in the MSDN. Have a look at Naresh Ravlani's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN is the best bet when you want to know the brief about things like properties, methods and how to use them. Here I got an [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties) for Canvas Class of System.Windows.Controls namespace. You can change namespace from the drop down and traverse between different classes and their properties, Inheritance Hierarchy, Syntax etc. I always use MSDN to refer to such things and I hope this will be helpful to you as well.